# Read FTP file contents to a string in C# FluentFTP

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, sftp, fluentftp

My class inherits from FluentFTP and I have created a class like this. I need to create a function called `Read` in this class. The purpose of the read function is to return a string to me by reading the contents of the files I have read from the FTP line by line. I'll process the rotating string later. Is there a method for this in FluentFTP? Ff there is none, how should I create the function?

```
using FluentFTP;

public class CustomFtpClient : FtpClient
{
    public CustomFtpClient(
            string host, int port, string username, string password) :
        base(host, port, username, password)
    {
        Client = new FtpClient(host, port, username, password);
        Client.AutoConnect();
    }

    private FtpClient Client { get; }

    public string ReadFile(string remoteFileName)
    {
        Client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
        return Client.ReadAllText(remoteFileName);
    }
}
```

I can't write like this because the `Client` I'm writing comes from FTP. Since I derived it from SFTP in my previous codes, I wanted to use a similar code snippet to it, but there is no such code snippet in FluentFTP. How should I perform an operation in the `Read` function?

In another file, I want to call it like this.

```
CustomFtpClient = new CustomFtpClient(ftpurl, 21, ftpusername, ftppwd);
var listedfiles = CustomFtpClient.GetListing("inbound");
var onlyedifiles = listedfiles.Where(z =>
    z.FullName.ToLower().Contains(".txt") || z.FullName.ToLower().Contains("940"))
    .ToList();

foreach (var item in onlyedifiles)
{
    //var filestr = CustomFtpClient.ReadFile(item.FullName);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read file to a string using FluentFTP, you can use [`FtpClient.DownloadStream` or `FtpClient.DownloadBytes`](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/wiki/File-Transfer) that either writes the file contents to `Stream` or `byte[]` array. The following examples uses the latter.

```
if (!client.Download(out byte[] bytes, "/remote/path/file.txt"))
{
    throw new Exception("Cannot read file");
}

string contents = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```